# JavaScript - Append to an element that cannot contain children using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several `<div>` elements for example, each one has the same class and contains 2 sibling. I want to append an element to the last sibling but that element cannot contain a children...

E.g

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"/> Checkbox 1
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox ">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox "/> Checkbox 2
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox ">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox "/> Checkbox 3
    </label>
  </div>
</div><!-- form-group -->
```

So my jQuery code is the following but it didn't work...

```
$(function() {
  var div = $("div"),
      $element = '<span></span>';
  div.each(function(i, el) {
    if (el.hasClass("class-name")) {
      $(el).nextAll().eq(1).append($element);
    }
  });
});
```

> I've included an `IF` statement for veryfication and only append the
>   element to the target (here I'm pointing to the `<input>` element as
>   the target) within the `<div>` only so the other elements will not be
>   included.

Any idea how to achieve that in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: `$('.class-name:last').append($("<span>"))`?

Comment: Show your desired output markup as your  description is somewhat less than clear.

Comment: append isn't the only method jquery offers for adding elements to the page. you also have .before(), .after(),

Comment: The only elements in your HTML that are siblings are the `<div>` elements themselves; those `<div>` elements contain a child `<label>` which itself contains a child `<input>`. And, whatever approach you use, you're not able to add a child to an `<input>` (but I'm unsure if that's what you want to do).

Comment: So to clarify with your edit you wish to append after the  last input?  Note to cannot append TO an input as it  is not the  proper type of element for that.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss  I know how it will become posible. If I use `$("input").parent().append($element);` then the problem is solved, but in my case I need to use an `IF` statement to append and verify if the `<input>` is within a `<div>` that has a class `checkbox`... I thought this is just a simple syntax error in my code that you guys can solve with ease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing your exact intent regarding the "children" comment I present three

This appends TO the last element:

```
$(function() {
  var div = $("div.class-name"),
    $element = '<span></span>';
  div.last().append($element);
});
```

This appends a new span AFTER the last one:

```
$(function() {
  var div = $("div.class-name"),
    $element = '<span></span>';
  div.last().after($element);
});
```

This replaces the last elements content with the span:

```
$(function() {
  var div = $("div.class-name"),
    $element = '<span></span>';
  div.last().html($element);
});
```

NOTE After your edit, I made the assumption you want to append a span after the last checkbox elements label so this does that:

```
$(function() {
  var div = $("div.checkbox");
  var lastelementwithnochildren = div.find('*:not(:has("*"))').last();
  $element = '<span>howdy</span>';
  lastelementwithnochildren.parent().append($element);
});
```

IF you want the span before the label text just after the input, change the last line to:

```
lastelementwithnochildren.after($element);
```

Comment: Your updated answer works but I want to append the `$element` to each `<input>` that is within a `<div>` that has a class `checkbox`. Sorry for the confusion that made someone downvote my question.

Comment: I found it bro TYVM for your answer. I just need to remove the `last()` part on your code and that's it. Case closed.